# Running N Erlang nodes and executing a line inside each one with a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, erlang, nodes

**TL;DR: How to send a line to a bash-launched program (and possibly run it in the background)?**

Hello there! I've tried quite a lot of solutions from around there but i haven't been able to combine them all into a working solution.

I want to make a bash script that runs N Erlang nodes, something like:

```
for i in {1..N}:
    erl -name server$i@127.0.0.1 -setcookie secret
```

And i want them to 'connect' them by pinging another node. To do this we can do:

```
erl -name some_server@127.0.0.1 -setcookie secret
(inside erlang)> net_adm:ping('another_server@127.0.0.1').
```

However i can't combine these two, even when trying it on a single node.

I've tried:

```
echo "net_adm:ping('another_server@127.0.0.1')." > erlang_command
cat erlang_command - | erl -name some_server@127.0.0.1 -setcookie secret

(i've had partial success with this one, i can run it manually but i couldn't make it to work to run in the background or in another terminal)
```

or

```
xterm -e "echo \"net_adm:ping('another_server@127.0.0.1').\"; cat erlang_command - | erl -name some_server@127.0.0.1 -setcookie secret"
```

Or other tricks like:

```
echo "net_adm:ping('another_server@127.0.0.1')." | erl -name some_server@127.0.0.1 -setcookie secret

-----

echo "net_adm:ping('another_server@127.0.0.1')." > /dev/stdin
erl -name some_server@127.0.0.1 -setcookie secret

-----

Some uses of nohup and & (can't remember these exactly, but got a similar experience)
nohup erl -name some_server@127.0.0.1 -setcookie secret &
```

However these either don't work or correctly executes the ping and finishes my erlang node, which i would like to keep running. What am i missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Piping input into an erl shell isn't a good way of executing short pieces of code. Either use something like `erl -noshell -name ... -setcookie ... -eval 'rpc:call(another_server@127.0.0.1, MODULE, FUNCTION, [ARGS]).'` (replace MODULE, FUNCTION and ARGS with whatever you want to do), or write an escript if you want to do something a bit longer than just a oneliner; see http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html for details.